# .NET SQL Computed column

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I have a column in a SQL Server table `TABLE1` that is computed using:

```
(checksum([Name], [Description], [ID], [Direction]))
```

I fill this `TABLE1` and then transfer the results to another table (`TABLE2`) that is identical except that the corresponding column in `TABLE2` is just integer and not computed. This allows me to change `Name`, `Description`, `ID` and `Direction` in `TABLE2` without affecting the integer that was originally in the computed column in `TABLE1`. This scenario has been working for years and cannot be changed.

Now I want to be able to populate `TABLE2` directly from .NET but want to use Name, Description, ID and Direction to create an integer (within .NET). It would be preferable if this was computed in exactly the same way that SQL Server does it but it's not absolutely necessary.

Comment: See the most upvoted answer, it has the code that you are looking for.

Comment: That's great. Just what I needed.